# Text in circle do responsive

Tags: css

I have circle with text:

```css
.circle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">0</div>
<div class="circle">100</div>
<div class="circle">10000</div>
```

In this example, when number is big, circle is not responsive. How I can do circles responsive with `width: 30px` and `height: 30px` ? I need only these sizes for circles.

Comment: You can use the wrap property , So if the text is longer than the circle then the remaining character willl go to the next line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following [padding-technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css) to make responsive circles:

```css
.circle {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.circle span {
    padding:60% 10%;
    margin-top:-0.6em;
    display:flex;
}
.circle span:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:0; left:0;
    width:120%;
    padding-bottom:120%;
    background-color:#eee;
    border-radius:50%;
    z-index:-1;
 }
```

```html
<div class="circle"><span>0</span></div>
<div class="circle"><span>100</span></div>
<div class="circle"><span>10000</span></div>
<div class="circle"><span>1000000000000</span></div>
```

EDIT:
If you want to circle size to stay the same but change the size of the font, here are various ways to achieve responsive font-size based on parent width:
https://css-tricks.com/fitting-text-to-a-container/

Comment: I don't need increase width.

Comment: then how do you want to make it responsive?

Comment: how I can do text responsive? But not circles. When number is 10000, then do small text

Comment: Not clear at all from your question, but here you can read about various ways to achieve responsive font-size based on container width: https://css-tricks.com/fitting-text-to-a-container/

Answer (score 0):

The responsiveness of the layout only applies when the webpage is resized or viewed on a different screen size (depending on the device). In your case, you might need to adjust the size of the circle or reduce the font size of the text. read more about responsive layout here https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp

```css
.circle {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">0</div>
<div class="circle">100</div>
<div class="circle">10000</div>
```